# Does $f(z)=\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)~\forall~z\in\mathbb C-\{0\}?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ such that $f\left(\dfrac{1}{n\pi}\right)=\sin\left(n\pi\right)~\forall ~n\in\mathbb Z.$

Does $f(z)=\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)~\forall~z\in\mathbb C-\{0\}?$

Comment: You know what $\sin(n\pi)$ is?

Comment: Hold on. $\sin (n\pi)=0~\forall~n.$ Thus $0$ satisfies the condition even though $\sin(\dfrac{1}{\pi/2})\neq 0.$ Right?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sriti: I don't see how $\sin(\frac{1}{\pi/2})$ is relevant.  But yes, $0$ is an example, or any function times $\sin(1/z)$.  Your observation that $0$ is a counterexample answers the question, and you could post it as an answer.

Comment: err I wanted to say even though $0$ satisfies the condition $0(\dfrac{2}{\pi})=0\ne\sin(\dfrac{1}{2/\pi})$

Answer (score 2):

even though $0$ satisfies the condition $0(\dfrac{2}{\pi})=0\ne\sin(\dfrac{1}{2/\pi})$